# Change the base font in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, font-size

I'm working a WordPress theme that has as a base Twitter Bootstrap. I'm using the twitter bootstrap sass for this. Also I have my own css which I put in Sass and everything comes together in my style.css.

Bootstrap is using the base-font variable, whicj is set on 14px. I want to have it on 15px. So I use my own _vars.scss where I did set the base font variable to 15px. But it doesn't take this in account. The base font doesn't change to 15px.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values in variables.scss are defined with !default attribute so the import order between _variables.scss and own_vars.scss should'nt be a problem. However be sure to import own_vars.scss **before** bootstrap.

Comment: Aha, I import it after Bootstrap because. I think that goes wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an order problem. 
Do you import your own_vars.scss before or after bootstrap.scss into your style.css?

(edit:) deleted wrong stuff

Comment: I had this. Kevin is giving the answer, it should be loaded before.

Comment: Ok, I didn't knew this !default feauture of sass. Nevermind then.